# PHP SQL Update Query failing

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to run this SQL query in PHP:

```
UPDATE 
    billing_calldata 
SET 
    status = 'c', 
    customer = '475', 
    description = 'UK Mobile VMNO C&W (fw7-C&W)', 
    customer_cost = '0.00720416666666667', 
    customer_ac = '0', 
    customer_sc = '0', 
    reseller_cost = '0', 
    reseller_ac = '0', 
    reseller_sc = '0'
```

WHERE 
        sequence = 10364723

but it is returning this error:

```
UPDATE 
    billing_calldata 
SET 
    status = 'c', 
    customer = '475', 
    description = 'UK Mobile VMNO CYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''UK Mobile VMNO C' at line 1
```

The `description` is `UK Mobile VMNO C&W (fw7-C&W)`

But the query work fine directly in `phpMyAdmin`

the query is originating from my vb.net application:

```
SQL = "UPDATE billing_calldata SET " _
                         & "status = 'c', " _
                         & "customer = '" & customer_sequence & "', " _
                         & "description = '" & description & "', " _
                         & "customer_cost = '" & customer_cost & "', " _
                         & "customer_ac = '" & customer_ac & "', " _
                         & "customer_sc = '" & customer_sc & "', " _
                         & "reseller_cost = '" & reseller_cost & "', " _
                         & "reseller_ac = '" & reseller_ac & "', " _
                         & "reseller_sc = '" & reseller_sc & "' " _
                         & "WHERE sequence = " & sequence & " "
                    SQL = "apikey=1nt3gr4&submittedSQL=" + SQL
```

then i send this in a Post request to a PHP page, which contains the following:

```
if($_POST["apikey"] <> '' and $_POST["apikey"] == '1nt3gr4' and $_POST["submittedSQL"] <> '') {
    $sql = $_POST["submittedSQL"];
    mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete coding lines of your php and tell us the structure of the table.

Comment: Read about escaping special characters in `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

Escape the special characters with [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php):

```
$description = $mysqli->real_escape_string($description);
```

then use `$description` in the `UPDATE`.

Comment: could i use this around the whole query ?

Comment: @charlie: No, you can't. You have to escape individually all the string values.

Comment: ive made an update, i wasnt sure if this would really make a difference because the query is technically being run on the PHP page and vb.net is just creating the query. check my question

Comment: @charlie: I don't know vbnet but I'm pretty sure it exists a function like `real_escape_string`